# JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale global reference

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, java-native-interface

I am trying to embedd unity android plugin and face an issue

this is the code:

```
public class Veedi : MonoBehaviour {

private static AndroidJavaObject VeediObject= null;
private static AndroidJavaObject activityContext = null;
public int DeveloperID;
public int gameID;
void Start() {
    print("**********START__________");
    if(VeediObject == null) {
        print("**********VeediObject________");

        using(AndroidJavaClass activityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
        {
            print("**********AndroidJavaClass_________");
            activityContext = activityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        }
        print("*******Before Init________");
        using(AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.play.im.MainActivity")) {
            if(pluginClass != null) {

                activityContext.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(() => 
                {
                    print("0");
                    int attach = AndroidJNI.AttachCurrentThread();
                print("1");


                    VeediObject = pluginClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");
                print("2");
                    VeediObject.Call("setContext", activityContext);
                print("3");
                    VeediObject.Call("initVeedi",gameID,DeveloperID);
                    print("**********after Init__________");

                }));



            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the code reach the line:

> VeediObject = pluginClass.CallStatic("instance");

It crahes in with a:

> JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale global reference

Someone suggested to use:

> AndroidJNI.NewGlobalRef

Can someone help with a direction to this problem? someone suggested its because the JNI refrence to the java objects changes

Answer (score 1):

The **C#** reference to **pluginClass** is lost as soon as the enclosing block is finished.

You are calling Java code on the **Android UI thread** which means that the lambda function you're passing as the 2nd argument in **AndroidJavaClass.Call** is executed at a later time after the block holding the reference for **pluginClass** is lost and hence your error.

You should keep a reference to **com.play.im.MainActivity** outside of the using block. You can keep a reference to it as a member of the MonoBehaviour.

```
private static AndroidJavaClass pluginClass;

void Start()
{
  ...
  pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.play.im.MainActivity");

  if(pluginClass != null) {

            activityContext.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(() => 
            {
                print("0");
                int attach = AndroidJNI.AttachCurrentThread();
            print("1");


                VeediObject = pluginClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");
            print("2");
                VeediObject.Call("setContext", activityContext);
            print("3");
                VeediObject.Call("initVeedi",gameID,DeveloperID);
                print("**********after Init__________");

            }));



        }
}
```